# Cross-compiling FontForge to iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cross-compiling, macos-carbon, fontforge

I am trying to cross compile FontForge's libs and binaries to armv7 but I seem to be running into several major issues.

Firstly, I am using SDK7.0 on Xcode 5.0.1.

On my first configure, I got several "error: cannot check for X while cross compiling"

Once I bypassed this, I realized the program was looking for Carbon (deprecated in the iOS SDK files for a long time now.)

Once I moved the old SDK files over, a TON of files were giving errors about unknown types (from _types.h, and all of its associated headers) most notable ssize and off_t.  Even after tinkering with these, I eventually get an "unsupported architecture" being reported from the sdk.
Here is my configure command:

```
./configure '--with-programs=yes' '--without-spiro' '--with-x=no' '--enable-static' '--with-cairo=no' '--without-python' '--with-pango=no' '--prefix=/Users/thebertolet/fontforge-ios' '--host=arm-apple-darwin' 'CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' 'CFLAGS=-mthumb -arch armv7 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/ -I/Users/thebertolet/freetype-ios/include/freetype2/ -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/' 'LDFLAGS=-mthumb -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/ -miphoneos-version-min=5.1'
```

Also of note: all of the required libs were required and reported to the program.  I guess my specific problem is the program trying to locate files that either don't exist or are somewhat unusable to armv7.

Alternatively, does anyone know of a great way (other than fontforge) to break ttc and combine ttf's?

Comment: I'd first ask if you even CAN compile FontForge for iOS. That seems like a daunting task. As for your other question, what is 'TTC'? As for combining TTFs, you can do that with fontForge on any other platform and then just export combined the font file to a new file.

Comment: I believe it is technically possible, as all of the required frameworks and processor support is there.  TTC files are multi-table TTF's.  And I need this project to use as an xcode library, so unfortunately I need to compile FontForge's libs on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely to be totally impossible. You can likely use the fontforge internals behind a Cocoa Touch front end, but fontforge is an X11 app in its native form with a custom widget set, and the only X servers for iOS seem to be for remote use of desktop Unix apps. You may have better luck on Android.